# MySQL How to adjust this query

Tags: mysql

This query returns tasks in lists only from logged in user. How to adjust this query so it returns something rather than nothing even if there is no tasks in list.

For example if logged in user tries to see the list that doesn't belong to him (other users list who has different id) this query will disallow that because it will return empty result. The problem is that it returns null if the list has no tasks even if it is that users(logged in) list.

If there is better way of doing this maybe in belonging php code please point it out.

Tables:

User: user_id (PK), user_name

---

List: list_id (PK), list_name, user_id (FK)

---

Task: task_id (PK), task_name, list_id (FK)

---

EDIT

This query should show list of tasks for specified list (list_id) and user id. In case user id doesn't match it should return NULL. In case that user has list but that list has no tasks it should return not NULL value so that list id still gets returned.

```
SELECT task_name, task_id, l.list_id 
FROM task AS t 
LEFT JOIN list AS l ON l.list_id = :list_id AND l.list_id = t.list_id 
WHERE l.user_id = :user_id 
ORDER BY t.task_id
```

Comment: No luck, that causes query to list all tasks regardless of user

Comment: Is it solved now? Otherwise consider providing proper DDLs and desired result.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: If i have :list_id as lets say 80 and user_id for example 45 i want query to return all tasks in list that has that (FK)list_id 80 and that belongs to user with user_id 45. If the list is empty (there is no task in task table that belongs to list with id 80 but there is list with id 80 that belongs to user with id 45) i want this query to return that empty list. I use this in a function that uses list_id and user_id as parameters and based on those parameters i'm viewing a certain list. It works with lists with at least one task but with empty ones it doesnt because query returns empty result.

Comment: users have lists and lists have tasks

Answer (score 1):

You have your `LEFT JOIN` backwards. `LEFT JOIN` should be followed by the table that might have no matches. So it should be:

```
SELECT task_name, task_id, list_id 
FROM list as l
LEFT JOIN task AS t
ON l.list_id = t.list_id
WHERE l.user_id = :user_id AND l.list_id = :list_id
ORDER BY t.task_id
```

Comment: This query returns all tasks in task table so it doesn't work.

Comment: What tasks is it supposed to return instead? You don't have any conditions limiting the tasks that should be returned.

Comment: You can't use a condition on the `list` table as the restriction, because you want to return tasks that have no matches in the `list` table, right? If there's nothing in the `list` table, how can we tell if the task should be returned or not?

Comment: It looks like you have the `LEFT JOIN` backwards. The way you wrote it, it returns tasks that have nothing in `list`. But you want lists that have nothing in `task`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in WHERE l.user_id = :user_id where no data in list no returned result even you used LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT task_name, task_id, list_id 
FROM task AS t 
LEFT JOIN list AS l ON l.list_id = :list_id AND l.list_id = t.list_id AND l.user_id = :user_id
ORDER BY t.task_id
```

Comment: It doesn't return user specific tasks(logged in user). It returns all tasks in task table. My query in the question works regarding user specific tasks but it returns NULL if the list is empty but does exist.  I'm using the query to list all users tasks in specific list

Comment: can you remove "l.list_id = :list_id AND" from your posted query

Comment: I need that because my function that shows tasks takes that as parameter and displays tasks of that list. It doesn't work when i take that out.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT t.task_name, t.task_id, l.list_id 
FROM task t 
LEFT JOIN list l WHERE l.list_id = :list_id AND l.list_id = t.list_id 
AND l.user_id = :user_id 
ORDER BY t.task_id
```